# Upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 - did not work

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

Eventually took the plunge and upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, various reasons for holding off
because of development work.

So Started the upgrade off, all seemed to go well, but now I have

1. No Internet connection - wired internet symbol has a '?' over it eventhough the machine has an IP addess and is connected to the router
2. No sound
3. Nvidia Graphics hasn't updated correctly
4. USB ports will only access certain memory sticks
5. Tried various Wifi Dongles and will not detect or setup eventhough they have been checked and were working before.
6. System extremely slow, minutes to open the file exporer etc.
7. Package install starts and then closes the screen.
8. Copying data to USB is slower than using a floppy drive
9. External backup drives took 30hrs to copy 250Gbytes of files. Older backup machine will complete this in 2 hrs.

(System is Dell precision 3420, i7-6600, 48Gb Ram, Nvidia P1000 Gfx, 1TB ssd, 1TB Hybrid, 2*27" + 1*32" screens)

I've tried Apt-offline - no help.

Is there anyway of running the upgrade again offline to try and re-install all components?
Will be a nightmare to reinstall from scratch.

(I know 22.04 works because I've since tried the Live USB boot and that works fine)

Comment: There's a lot of options available which mostly lead to a dead end. Whatever you do you'll probably have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: The question you are asking in your issue description should possibly be mentioned in the title of the issue (after searching it using search engine).